# Static block is not being called

Tags: java, final

Who can explain what's going on?

```
public class MagicFinal {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(A.s);
    }
}

class A {
    static {
        System.out.println("class has been loaded");
    }

    public static final String s = "final";

    public static final Integer i = 3;
    
        
}
```

**Console :**

> final

What's it? I don't understand why the class has not been loaded, I know classes always load at the first call. Field `s` is in pool of string, I see that final modifier is magic.

If I delete final modifier (`public static String s = "final"` ) I will get

**Console :**

> class has been loaded
>
> final

Note: I have changed field `i` : `public static final int i = 3;` and show it in console.
I got the same as in String situation. Why?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

`"final"` is a *string literal* and as such is a [*compile-time constant expression*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28). The value of a `static final` variable initialized with a compile-time constant expression is directly hardcoded into the class which references it, and no reference is made to the originating class. Therefore the initialization of the originating class does not occur.

As a side point, please note the distinction between class *loading* and class *initialization*: only the latter's occurrence is precisely specified by the JLS. Class loading can happen at any time.

Comment: Ok , thank's a lot !! What about int ??
public static final int i = 3; // wont write class has been loaded
public static final Integer i = 3; // write class has been loaded

Comment: Please read the definition of compile-time constant expression to which I have linked in my answer. `int` is a primitive value, `String` is the only special case of a reference-typed value which can be involved in a constant expression, and `Integer` is neither.

Comment: @marko  - Are you telling me that Class A is not getting loaded at all?? or is it a case of lazy initialization???

Comment: @X86 If `"class has been loaded"` doesn't print, then the class has not been initialized. Classes are always initialized lazily, as per the JLS. Class A may get *loaded* at any point or not at all, subject to the decision by the JVM runtime. Note that class loading is not supposed to cause any observable effects.

Comment: I am sorry.. But I am still not quite getting it... A class may or may not be loaded... But once a class is loaded, it is initialized lazily.. is this correct??.. And in this case, String constants are substituted in the class, so, initialization of the class is not yet done.. only loading is done.. right?

Comment: @x86 I don't follow you. Class A is not being initialized at all if the field in it is `static final`. It may or may not be loaded, but that has nothing to do with this story. It will most probably not be loaded, but there's nothing stopping the JVM from doing so.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik The last paragraph of your answer prompted [this question of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19100002/1527084)

Answer (score 3):

This is what is written in Java Language Specification {8.3.2.1 Initializers for Class Variables}. This must answer your question

> One subtlety here is that, at run time, static variables that are final and that
>   are initialized with compile-time constant values are initialized first. This also
>   applies to such fields in interfaces (§9.3.1). These variables are “constants” that
>   will never be observed to have their default initial values (§4.12.5), even by devious
>   programs. See §12.4.2 and §13.4.9 for more discussion.

Comment: Seems like you're referring to *The Java Language Specification, Third Edition*. There are no such paragraph in *The Java® Language Specification Java SE 7 Edition*.

Comment: Yes. That is right. I was looking into old edition but the statement holds good for JLS 7 as well. Below lines are from JLS7

At run-time, static fields that are final and that are initialized with constant
expressions (§15.28) are initialized first (§12.4.2). This also applies to such fields
in interfaces (§9.3.1). These fields are "constants" that will never be observed to
have their default initial values (§4.12.5), even by devious programs (§13.4.9).